# haml-rails doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I've been working for the last two days (not long enough, it seems) to getting `haml-rails` to work with this RoR application. The backtrace I'm getting is this:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template customcare360/login, application/login with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/var/www/clients/client1/web54/capistrano/releases/20130403223833/app/views"
):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3579697130236064177__process_action__869676858511540114__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3196186370685956669__call__1689534214956595528__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
  unicorn (4.6.2) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/ageless360-patient.theblsgroup.net/capistrano/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /var/www/ageless360-patient.theblsgroup.net/capistrano/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

I've tried manually loading 'haml-rails' into my `config/application.rb`. My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Environment-independent gems
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'json'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# HAML up the HTML.
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'

group :development do
  # Provides an intuitve means of debugging in the browser.
  gem 'better_errors'

  # Remove unnecessary assets from being logged at dev time.
  gem 'quiet_assets'

  # Deploy with Capistrano
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
  gem 'capistrano-unicorn'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
end
```

Comment: A similar issue reported to the Haml issues (https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/653), but I can’t reproduce it. Does everything work in the dev environment? Would it be possible for you to provide a (minimal) app where this issue happens?

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my development environment here. I could try but it'd take me a while since it's a proprietary codebase I'm working on for a client. 

(Should have removed some paths above as well).

Comment: It does look related. My production environment includes *haml* and *haml-rails*.

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with Capistrano and Unicorn. If Unicorn is using an old Gemfile when it reloads itself then Haml won’t get loaded. Have you recently added Haml to the Gemfile?